# Are there any "fast" algorithms for defragmenting memory?

Tags: big-o-notation, memory-management

This is about memory, not files or filesystems.

So in a typical process, imagine you have a string "Hello world" that later gets changed to "Hello". Or a list of 100 objects later gets reduced to 50. Or a dynamic array, or other datastructures.

This produces wasted space in memory. It's not solved with virtual memory because that's just a remapper. Memory still has to be allocated in pages, say 64 KB large, so any reduction in the size of some object, array, string, etc., will produce more wasted space than was previously there.

I tried to hunt for an algorithm for memory defragmentation but almost every result is about filesystems, not memory. I would really like to look at some and see what is their Big O notation.

Are there any memory defrag algorithms that can do it in O(n) time? What is the best one known?

Is this sort of thing just not implemented in modern OSs because of huge constant overhead?

Answer (score 1):

Most memory allocators don't do memory defragmentation at the level of individual objects.  Instead, when the process next allocates new objects that are the same size or smaller, the allocator will reuse the space from some previously deallocated object.  (If all objects placed a single page have been deallocated, then the page can potentially be released, but many allocators don't do that; they just reuse it for future allocations.)

Pages are typically 4K bytes, not 64 KB bytes.

To do memory defragmentation in the way you are imagining, you would have to move around objects within memory, which would change the address of those objects.  So, you'd have to find all references to those objects in memory and adjust the address of each reference.  This is most naturally done using garbage collection.  So, for languages that don't use garbage collection (like C or C++), memory defragmentation would be very difficult (basically impossible) to implement.